# filter range must be a single row or a single column

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am receiving an error using below formula that is working perfect in excel but not in google Sheets

filter range must be a single row or a single column. your help will be much appreciated.

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K1,A2:B1000))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=SORT({FILTER(A2:B1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K1,A2:A1000)));FILTER(A2:B1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(K1,B2:B1000)))})
```